# If statement in access queries in choosing 2 prices from 1 product based on Quantity Ordered

Tags: ms-access

So, lets say I have 3 tables.
First table is the product table where it consists of

***Prod_code, Prod_name, Prod_qty, Prod_Price1, Prod_Price2***.

The second table is the Order table where it consists of

***Order_ID, Order_Date, Total_price***.

And the last table is the order detail table which consists of

***Order_Detail_ID, Order_ID (foreign key from order table), Prod_code(foreign key from Product table), Qty_Ordered, and Price***

If you can see I have 2 prices for each product in the product table for the purpose of:

1. If the *Qty_ordered* from the order detail table is greater than 10 unit, then the *Price* column in the order detail given will be *Prod_price2*
2. If the *Qty_ordered* from the order detail table is equal to or less than 10 unit, then *Price* column in the order detail given will be *Prod_price1*

How can I make this happen so when I create an order detail form, it can automatically give me the Product price based on the *Qty_ordered* that I input?
I believe this could require some if statements in the query but I'm a novice in Ms. Access and I need you guys' help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Total_Price should be calculated from OrderDetails, not saved in Orders.

Answer (score 0):

In a query that joins Orders and Products to OrderDetails, calculate a field with:
`IIf(Qty_Ordered <= 10, Prod_Price1, Prod_Price2)`

If you need to display this on data entry form bound to OrderDetails, build a combobox that lists products and has both prices as columns (can be hidden if you want). An expression in textbox can reference columns of combobox by their index. So if Price1 is in third column its index is 2.
`=IIf(Qty_Ordered <= 10, Me.cbxProduct.Column(2), Me.cbxProduct.Column(3))`

Saving this calculated result will require code (macro or VBA) in some event, probably form BeforeUpdate.
`Me!Price = Me.tbxPrice`

Comment: Thank you a lot dear sir! I will try this immediately!

Comment: In the query Should I write the calculation under the Price field of the Order Detail table?

Comment: Use the query with calculated field approach only if you are not saving result to table. And no, calculation cannot be under OrderDetails Price field.